# Edge Browser WebDriver Failure

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Attempting to make the code from http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/ work.

Getting an ugly exception.

Repro steps.

Install web driver from links provided ( July 24 2015 WebDriver )
Create console app.
Nuget in Selenium.WebDriver, Selenium.Support.
Run code,  console window comes up fine.

When code hits the driver.Url="https://www.bing.com" it throws an exception, as noted below.

NoSuchWindowException - An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

My snippet is below:

```
using System.IO;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
namespace WebDriverPlay
{
public class msedgedev_sample
{
    public static void RunMSEdgeDevSample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("running MSEdgeDev Sample");
        RemoteWebDriver driver = null;
        string serverPath = "Microsoft Web Driver";
        try
        {
            if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                serverPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%"), serverPath);
            }
            else
            {
                serverPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%"), serverPath);
            }

            // location for MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
            EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
            driver = new EdgeDriver(serverPath, options);

            //Set page load timeout to 5 seconds
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            //string _url = @"https://www.bing.com/";
            string _url = @"http://www.google.com";
            Console.WriteLine("_url=" + _url);
            driver.Url = _url;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (driver != null)
            {
                driver.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

After the line:

driver = new EdgeDriver(serverPath, options);

executes, you should see a command window open and connect to Edge. If the Edge browser is already open, it will close it and open a new instance.  Based on your error, I don't believe you are seeing this behavior, am I correct? If so, something may be blocking the WebDriver Server from launching locally (Defender??). Check the conditional setting serverPath. I could not get the Is64BitOperatingSystem to resolve, so I chose the correct path and removed the rest of the conditional, setting serverPath to the location of the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe.

If you have the incorrect path it will not make it past the "driver" instantiation. Somehow you are making it to the driver.Url call, I assume you are getting some resolution with that serverPath. So it is possible something on the local device is blocking MicrosoftWebDriver.exe from running.

Again, you should see a command prompt with proper communication logging displayed.

One last tip, you can go to MicrosoftWebDriver.exe and run it. Then you can go to: http://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/webdriver/ and "Send Request" with the default values, which should be to create a session. You will see the results posted to the page and also see the logging of the communications in the command window.

Be sure to go to that page from a different browser than Edge since it will kill the existing Edge windows, including itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have a little insight, but not a workaround or fix, yet...

in my case, the web driver server for IE conflicted with my web driver server for edge... and I still do not have a workaround... I have a cycle of tests that run on five different browsers.

when I tried to add edge, it would not run edge without crashing.
the web driver in the debug folder (for the base five including IE) name is IDENTICAL to the one that is included when I run Edge.

I do not know how to fix it and meet the testing requirements... YET.
bro mak